# Eclipse+CDTのgdbデバッグについてscanfで入力するとxx-thread-selectが勝手に入力される

Tags: windows, eclipse, gdb

開発環境についての質問です。
　現在、Eclipse+CDTを使ってWindows上でC言語をプログラミングをしています。
　MinGW GCC環境のgdbを使ってデバッグすると、scanfでうまく入力できずに困っています。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[10];

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("%s\n", string); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

文字をscanfで入力してそのままprintfで出力するプログラムで、Eclipseで実行しても正しい結果を得ることができるのですが、Eclipseのデバッガでデバッグすると、

「ようこそC言語へ」と入力すると、

「44-thread-select」と出力されてしまいます。

コマンドラインでgdbデバッグをすると、ちゃんと実行できることから、Eclipse上の問題と考えられるのですが、どこか設定しなければいけなかったところがあるのでしょうか？
　それとも、Eclipseの仕様なんでしょうか？

初心者のような質問ですが、回答よろしくお願いします。

スペック
・OS：windows 10 Pro
・Eclipse：Eclipse Neon.3(4.6.3)
・gcc：gcc version 7.1.0 (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
・gdb：GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
・Eclipse CDT：9.2.1.201703062208
・Eclipse CDT SDK：9.2.1.201703062208
・Eclipse GDB Common：9.2.1.201703062208